# Ubuntu sdk with out emulator

Tags: ubuntu-touch, emulation, sdk

Hello I would like to start making apps for ubuntu touch. The main problem is that my emulator freezes when I start it (including My whole computer), so I would like to use my real phone (aquaris E5) to test My apps in. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.
As far as I remember, you have to enable Developer Mode in your device (Settings > About this phone) and connect it to your PC via USB.
Open the IDE and it should be added automatically in the "Devices" section.

Comment: I am not currently on My ubuntu computer. But when I connected my phone it said something like "program running in background", but I'll comback to you on that. BTW thanks